# Luke 17. Do these two verses speak contrary to a pre-trib rapture?

Tags: exegesis, eschatology, gospel-of-luke, rapture

Luke 17:32, 33

> <sup>**32**</sup> Remember Lot's wife. <sup>**33**</sup> Whosoever shall seek to save his life shall lose it; and whosoever shall lose his life shall preserve it.

Do these two verses contradict with the idea of being taken out seven years before Jesus' second coming?

Comment: @RHPclass79 - Do you mean rapture in your second paragraph?

Comment: @Vincent Wong l guess I am confused by your question. Given the original question and subsequent clarification in the body, how would you interpret differently. Please explain.

Comment: @RHPclass79- I am not clear about the phrase 'being taken out seven years before Jesus' second coming'. Where is the origin of this script?

Comment: @ Vincent Wong. Thank you for responding back Vincent. In the denomination of Church I go to the pretrib point of view involves the Church being raptured 7 years before the 2nd coming. There are other opinions on that . The basis for that 7 years comes from the Daniel Ch.9:24-27 verses.

Comment: This is a question about the understanding of a text in relation to a doctrine held by a subset of Christians.  It does not ask about the meaning of the text itself.  Personally, I do not understand how this text any bearing on the subject the timing of eschatological turbulation.

Comment: Well then I will try to explain my logic. Jesus said the servant is not greater than his master. Just as Jesus was pesecuted, so shall we be. In this context Jesus seems to carry that thought even further that we will have to die. I wonder whether those of a pretrib doctrine are trying to eisogete something into the scriptures ( that I don't see) just to escape in their mind what the SCRIPTURES actually present.

Comment: The *so called* "Rapture" is a contentious subject and best left alone for it is just going to result in opinion based answers. The same goes for the "70th Week" of Daniel, and I should know as I have brought same up a number of times. As for **Luke 17:32&33**, I would have thought that that, itself, is easy enough to understand. If one is *still* around and showing *true* faith at the time of the "2nd Coming", then there should be no need to seek preservation of one's life. Live or die, the *ultimate* result will be life eternal, in either heaven or on earth, both of which will be made anew.

Comment: @ Olde English This is one topic I think we would mostly agree on. For every one verse that is used to support the John Darby doctrine there are five that prove otherwise. False teaching has dire consequences and it is not opinionated at all when the playing field is not stacked. For twenty years I have debated this topic. Those that were arrogant promised they could prove their point only to fail miserably.

Answer (score 0):

No, they do not.  The verses in question pertain to Israel, not the church, the body of Christ.  The body of Christ "mystery" was still not yet revealed at the time of the Luke verses.

There is no doubt that the church, the body of Christ, will experience the 'catching away' that Paul references below:

**1 Thessalonians 4:13-18**

> "But I would not have you to be ignorant, brethren, concerning them which are asleep, that ye sorrow not, even as others which have no hope.
> 14 For if we believe that Jesus died and rose again, even so them also which sleep in Jesus will God bring with him.
> 15 For this we say unto you by the word of the Lord, that we which are alive and remain unto the coming of the Lord shall not prevent them which are asleep.
> 16 For the Lord himself shall descend from heaven with a shout, with the voice of the archangel, and with the trump of God: and the dead in Christ shall rise first:
> 17 Then we which are alive and remain shall be caught up together with them in the clouds, to meet the Lord in the air: and so shall we ever be with the Lord.
> 18 Wherefore comfort one another with these words."

The verses cited in Luke were written directly to and for Israel, not the church, the body of Christ (us today).  There is nothing in scripture (prior to Paul) stating that a group would ever be caught up in heaven upon Christ's second coming.  He will return to earth to establish Israel's long-awaited and promised earthly kingdom of heaven after the church, the body of Christ has been "caught up" with Him for eternity.  Notice below that the coming wrath of God will not be poured out on the church, the body of Christ (verses 4 and 9 in particular):

**1 Thessalonians 5:1-11**

> "But of the times and the seasons, brethren, ye have no need that I write unto you.
> 2 For yourselves know perfectly that the day of the Lord so cometh as a thief in the night.
> 3 For when they shall say, Peace and safety; then sudden destruction cometh upon them, as travail upon a woman with child; and they shall not escape.
> 4 But ye, brethren, are not in darkness, that that day should overtake you as a thief.
> 5 Ye are all the children of light, and the children of the day: we are not of the night, nor of darkness.
> 6 Therefore let us not sleep, as do others; but let us watch and be sober.
> 7 For they that sleep sleep in the night; and they that be drunken are drunken in the night.
> 8 But let us, who are of the day, be sober, putting on the breastplate of faith and love; and for an helmet, the hope of salvation.
> 9 For God hath not appointed us to wrath, but to obtain salvation by our Lord Jesus Christ,
> 10 Who died for us, that, whether we wake or sleep, we should live together with him.
> 11 Wherefore comfort yourselves together, and edify one another, even as also ye do."

Comment: @ Mark Vestal where did you conclude from this scripture in Luke, that the Church would go through God's wrath? I agree with 1Th. Ch.5 that the Church does not experience God's wrath ( orge ). Your quoted verses are classic verses used by pre- trib advocates. They confuse God's wrath ( orge or thumos) with tribulation ( thlipsis). The Olivet prophecy is not addressed to just Israel as you suggest. It is addressed to the disciples, which are the beginning of the church. Jesus first offered his Good News to his fellow Jews, then to Gentiles via Peter and Paul. Mt. 24, Mr. 13. TBC

Comment: Mt. 24 and Mk. 13 are clear on the gathering of the Saints after the tribulation. Luke 21 is also Olivet prophecy but is constructed differently. Regardless of all this you might address the answer  more specifically on the Luke 17: 32&33 verses given.

Comment: @RHPclass79 Peter's church of believing Jews is not the same church as Paul's church, the body of Christ.  Paul's church is "caught up in the clouds".  Peter's believing remnant is "taken"...as in taken to safety (like Noah), "as in the days of Noah". There is no mention of being "taken to heaven" in Matt, Mark, Luke, John, or Acts (unlike Paul's church, the body of Christ, in 1 Thess). Regarding the gospel, what was the good news of the twelve as given by Christ on earth and who was this good news directed to?  It was that Israel's long awaited earthly kingdom of heaven was finally at hand.

Comment: @RHPclass79 What was Paul's good news that Christ ascended gave to him to NOW bring to the world?  That our sins have been forgiven through the shed blood of Jesus Christ, and that we are NOW offered the free unmerited gift of salvation by faith in what Christ completed for us at the cross.  (cont...)

Comment: @RHPclass79 1 Cor 15:1-4 "Moreover, brethren, I declare unto you the gospel which I preached unto you, which also ye have received, and wherein ye stand;
2 By which also ye are saved, if ye keep in memory what I preached unto you, unless ye have believed in vain.
3 For I delivered unto you first of all that which I also received, how that Christ died for our sins according to the scriptures;
4 And that he was buried, and that he rose again the third day according to the scriptures:"

Comment: @RHPclass79 Notice that there are 2 gospels mentioned here:  Gal 2:7-9 "But contrariwise, when they saw that the gospel of the uncircumcision was committed unto me, as the gospel of the circumcision was unto Peter;
8 (For he that wrought effectually in Peter to the apostleship of the circumcision, the same was mighty in me toward the Gentiles:)
9 And when James, Cephas, and John, who seemed to be pillars, perceived the grace that was given unto me, they gave to me and Barnabas the right hands of fellowship; that we should go unto the heathen, and they unto the circumcision."

Comment: @RHPclass79 Both groups of these believers are "in Christ" (Israel's believing remnant, and the body of Christ), but Israel is the one of earth, and the church, the body of Christ is heavenly (Paul's church...us).  Both groups come together when time is complete:  Eph 1:10 "That in the dispensation of the fulness of times he might gather together in one all things in Christ, both which are in heaven, and which are on earth; even in him:"

Comment: @RHPclass79  You can see then that the statement that the church, the body of Christ, is who is NOT subject to wrath or tribulation, but Israel who must "endure to the end", is.

Comment: There is only one Gospel. Mk. 16:15 commands " Go ye into all the world, and preach the Gospel to every creature." This is the great commission. Jesus told "all" in the Olivet prophecy to watch-Mk.13:37.  The verse you quoted from Gal is referring to two apostelships. Paul enduringly refers to the Gospel of Jesus as his gospel for Jesus entrusted him to deliver it to the Gentiles.

Comment: @ moderator And leave everyone that has read this confused. I hope not. I am trying to be nice to every one concerned, but two gospels, a different one to the Jews and then the Gentiles. This is what Paul warned of in the epistle to the Galatians.

Comment: @RHPclass79 Christ on earth is addressing Israel. Matthew 15:24
"But he answered and said, I am not sent but unto the lost sheep of the house of Israel." Acts 11:19 "Now they which were scattered abroad upon the persecution that arose about Stephen travelled as far as Phenice, and Cyprus, and Antioch, preaching the word to none but unto the Jews only."  We follow Christ's heavenly ministry today (given to Paul), not earthly:  2 Corinthians 5:16 "Wherefore henceforth know we no man after the flesh: yea, though we have known Christ after the flesh, yet now henceforth know we him no more."

Comment: @RHPclass79 Paul received "his gospel" from Christ ascended, not from Peter:  Galatians 1:11-12 "But I certify you, brethren, that the gospel which was preached of me is not after man.
12 For I neither received it of man, neither was I taught it, but by the revelation of Jesus Christ."

Comment: @RHPclass79 Peter and the 11 preached the coming of Israel's long awaited earthly kingdom of heaven finally being "at hand".  Paul, however, was given "the word of reconciliation".  1 Corinthians 1:23 "But we preach Christ crucified, unto the Jews a stumblingblock, and unto the Greeks foolishness;"  2 Corinthians 5:19 "To wit, that God was in Christ, reconciling the world unto himself, not imputing their trespasses unto them; and hath committed unto us the word of reconciliation."

Comment: One last comment. Mark you need to answer for yourself how the Gentiles ( the wild olive) tree is grafted into the original olive tree Israel-Rom11:17-24. Then Rom.10:11-13 & Gal.3:26-29. Hope these verses clear up that the only one Gospel is the same salvation for Jews and Gentiles alike. Blindness in part has happened to Israel until the fullness of the Gentiles comes in (Rom.11:25-26).

Comment: @RHPclass79 Grafted into access (Eph 2:18) of "the olive tree" does not mean that the church, the body of Christ, is grafted into God's covenant promise program with Israel. The church, the body of Christ, is God's heavenly body of believers. Israel is God's earthly body of believers. We will not come together as one until the fullness of times has arrived. Eph 1:10 "That in the dispensation of the fulness of times he might gather together in one all things in Christ, both which are in heaven, and which are on earth; even in him:" The church and Israel are both "in Christ". but separate.

Comment: @ Mark Vestal I am glad you brought up Ephesians. Read Ch:2:10-14 . This should clarify that Gentiles(aliens from the Commonwealth of Israel ) are made nigh by the blood of Jesus. Also I noticed you ignored Gal.3:26-29. Gal.6:15-16 For in Christ Jesus neither circumcision availeth any thing, nor uncircumcision, but a new creature.

Comment: @RHPclass79 Correct. Every believer today (Jew or Gentile) are of the same body.  We ALL have the same access to God through "faith in His blood".  That is not stated before Paul came.  Those who believed Christ was the Messiah (prior to Paul) belong to Peter's church at Pentecost of believing Jews (the little flock).  All are "in Christ", but the church, the body of Christ, is not a part of Peter's Jewish church of believers.  They still await their promised earthly kingdom to come (at the "times of refreshing").  The "mystery" of the body of Christ is never mentioned before revealed to Paul.

Comment: 1st and 2nd Peter are written to Gentiles. The conversion of Cornelius and his family proved the Gospel was then opened to the Gentiles and Jews alike, depending on who believe and accept it. There is only one Gospel. The original question was on Lot's wife, which was an example of what should not be done. If you have a comment on that, offer it now or write your own question on this 2 gospel topic.

Comment: 1 Peter 2:9-12 disagree with you, as does Gal 2:7-9 "But contrariwise, when they saw that the gospel of the uncircumcision was committed unto me, as the gospel of the circumcision was unto Peter;
8 (For he that wrought effectually in Peter to the apostleship of the circumcision, the same was mighty in me toward the Gentiles:)
9 And when James, Cephas, and John, who seemed to be pillars, perceived the grace that was given unto me, they gave to me and Barnabas the right hands of fellowship; that we should go unto the heathen, and they unto the circumcision."  Lot and his wife were of Israel.

Comment: @ Mark Vestal Acts 26:19-23 Paul first offers the Gospel to his fellow Jews and then the Gentiles. The great commission is preached to all nations Mt.28:19-20. Same GOSPEL to all nations. You are ignoring all the scriptures that do no fit your preconceived ideas. Post a question on your own to this topic.

Comment: I cited 5 verses above (including from Matthew) that states "Jew only".  I cannot come up with a question that will adhere to the requirement of pertaining to denominational religious doctrine, even though the word "religion" is never viewed in a positive light with Paul.  I will ask you directly though. I agree that there is NOW only 1 gospel.  I know that ALL scripture is profitable for our learning, but with that said; could someone find the message of salvation if only given the epistles of Paul to read (Roman's through Philemon)?  If not, why?

Comment: @MarkVestal You made this statement: "I cited 5 verses above (including from Matthew) that states "Jew only". At Matthew 24:3 the disciples came to Jesus and ask Him privately, "Tell us, when will these things be, and what will be the sign of Your coming, and of the end of the age/world.? Then at Matthew 24:14 Jesus says, "And this gospel of the kingdom shall be preached in the WHOLE WORLD for a witness to all the nations, AND THEN THE END WILL COME." So how do you reconcile your view of the "Jew only" with what Jesus said?

Comment: @Mr.Bond That "end" would be the end of Israel's trib. The 144k would be preaching (yes, to the entire world) during that period (prior to the 1k years). This was the anticipated time to come after Christ's ascension. Believing Israel was eagerly awaiting it (Acts 1:6). However, they were not clued in on the current age of God's grace, appropriated to Paul (Eph 3:2), that would separate the time then to that time yet future. This near 2,000 year "hidden" time of salvation being offered freely to anyone who will simply believe, and without having to first go through the priestly nation Israel